# How to find the index of a missing value in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array like

```
a=[1,2,3,,4,5];
```

So now I want to find the missing value index, i.e. `3`, using `indexOf`.

Answer (score 6):

Check if the value is `undefined` like the following code:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < a.length; i++ ) {
    if ( typeof a[i] === "undefined" ) {
        // do stuff here or break the loop
    }
}
```

**Update**
You can do this too:

```
Array.prototype.indexOfUndefined =  function() {
    for ( var i = 0; i < this.length; i++ ) {
        if ( typeof this[i] === "undefined" ) {
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

You need to return `i` because `i` is the current index, it will search for the first `undefined` value.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vdyypq6o/5/

Comment: Thanks dude. We know this way but i want to find using indexOf method

Comment: @Thinker: You can't. You'd want `a.indexOf(undefined)`, but that doesn't work, because your array doesn't have any entry at all at index 3, and so `indexOf` doesn't look at it. See steps 9(a) and 9(b): http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.14

Comment: @Thinker: if you do `a.indexOf(undefined)`, it will return -1. but What he need is, to return the i index. :)

Comment: @Thinker: If your array were `a=[1, 2, 3, undefined, 4, 5]`, then `indexOf` would work, because the array would have an entry at index 3 with the value `undefined`. But with the array as you've quoted it, there's no entry there at all.

Comment: There's no purpose to the `break`; in your edit. It's dead code, it will never be reached.

Comment: you need fix your function: first, you use global var `a` inside function, second, you add function to prototype, but not use **this** and therefore have `a.indexOfUndefined(a)` instead just `a.indexOfUndefined()`. Also function return wrong answer for next array: `[undefined,1,2,3,,4,5]`

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina but why you add `this.indexOf("undefined")`?

Comment: @Grundy: sorry, I made a mistake! ;)

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina, so, your method find not only _missed_ value, but _undefined_ values too

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, ES5 Array methods are required* to skip such array holes**, so no `indexOf()` or `forEach()` will help. ECMAScript 2015 has two new methods called `find()` and `findIndex()` that could help you, but they are not [widely supported yet](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#Array.prototype_methods_Array.prototype.findIndex), so I assume it's not a good answer for this question.

What's left is a good old iteration over indexes:

```
function findHole(a) {
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        // check for only `a[i] === undefined` could be faster,
        // but is not enough as it will cause false positives
        // when array actually contains `undefined` value
        // for example, for `a = [1, undefined, , 2]`,
        // correct implementation should return `2`, not `1`
        if (a[i] === undefined && !a.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
           console.log("Found hole at index " + i);
           return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

* — see step 9 in http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.14 for `indexOf()` and step 8 http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.19 for `map()` algorithms that require skipping holes

** — a hole is created in array when there's no value defined for some index, so technically it's not  correct to say that `a[3]` has `null` or `undefined` value, because there just isn't any value. But in JavaScript, when we try to get not defined property of some object, what we get is `undefined`, that why `a[3] === undefined` is true.

Comment: *"btw, index 3 has undefined value, not null"* Actually, it doesn't have a value **at all**, because it's not there. If it were there, with the value `undefined`, `indexOf(undefined)` would find it.

Comment: Actually index 3 has a value. Its both null and undefined. See the link: http://jsfiddle.net/x6npohz6/1/

Comment: @Thinker: No, it doesn't. What you're seeing there is 1) When you retrieve a property of an object (and standard arrays are just objects) that *doesn't exist at all* (on the object or in its prototype chain), you get back `undefined`. That doesn't mean the property exists; it doesn't. It's just how property retrieval is defined. 2) `==` does type coercion, and `undefined == null` is `true`.

Comment: @Thinker try use '===' instead '=='

Comment: Thanks, @T.J.Crowder! You're correct and I've removed this claim from my answer and added some clarification about why it looks like holes have `undefined` values.

Comment: This seems to be the only answer that will ignore an explicit `undefined` value within the array.  +1

Comment: methinks you can reduce condition to `!a.hasOwnProperty(i)` because if not this property so element automatically _undefined_

Comment: @Grundy, yes, you're right, but `a[i] === undefined` provides a nice quick filter before calling slower `hasOwnProperty()`, so looking for hole in array without holes or `undefined` values will be really quick. Here's some perf test: http://jsperf.com/findhole

Comment: @sainaen, not thinking about this, but you right - it faster :-)

Comment: @sainaen, my version is almost as fast as your without `a[i] === undefined` :-D : http://jsperf.com/findhole/2

Comment: @Grundy well, it is, but only because of `console.log()` in my functions. Check this version of test, where your version is 96% slower http://jsperf.com/findhole/3 ;-D

Comment: @sainaen, eh, ~10% slowly from case `without a[i]===undefined`

Comment: @Grundy, I've compared it with algorithm from this answer, because function without `a[i] === undefined` check is only there to show why it's required. But your version is interesting, I certainly wouldn't think about using `reduce()` this way, thanks for sharing it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79401/discussion-between-sainaen-and-grundy).

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,3,,4,5];
i = 0;
$.each(a , (function(){
  if(a[i]=="") {
    alert(i + ":: yes this is null index");
  }
  i++;
});
```

you can use the each loop for this purpose.
May be there are more solutions for this purpose in market :P but this is also a good one. you should try this.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding another way to achieve what you need -

```
for ( var i = 0; i < a.length; i++ ) {
    if (!a[i]) {
      console.log("Null index = ",i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```js
                  a=['1','2','3',,'4']
            
            for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
              {
               if( a.indexOf(a[i])==-1)
                 // if(typeof a[i] == 'undefined')
                    alert("Index-->"+i)
              }
```

Comment: Lol seriously ? This is similar to the upvoted answer of Radonirina which was provided 10 minutes ago...

Comment: Yah I realised after posting.

Comment: That's what the "delete" link under the answer is for. :-)

Comment: I think, the changed answer can fullfill your requirement.

Comment: I thought you are trying to use indexOf, thats why I tried.  It is also not any copy of another answer. and previously I did not copy anything intentionally.

Comment: If you're going to loop through the array, using `indexOf` is nonsensical. (***I'm*** not trying to do anything; the OP is trying to find the missing entry in his/her array.)

Comment: Then, trying to define something undefined is also nonsensical

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way with [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function, getting all missed values.

```
function findMissed(arr){
    var result = arr.reduce(function(acc,el,index){
        if(index - acc.cur > 1) {
            for(var i=acc.cur+1;i < index;i++){
                acc.res.push(i);
            }
        }
        acc.cur = index;
        return acc;
    },{cur:-1,res:[]});
    var missed = result.res;
    if(result.cur !== arr.length){
      for(var i=result.cur+1;i<arr.length;i++){
          missed.push(i);
      }
    }
    return missed;
}
```

```js
function findMissed(arr) {
  var result = arr.reduce(function(acc, el, index) {
    if (index - acc.cur > 1) {
      for (var i = acc.cur + 1; i < index; i++) {
        acc.res.push(i);
      }
    }
    acc.cur = index;
    return acc;
  }, {
    cur: -1,
    res: []
  });
  var missed = result.res;
  if (result.cur !== arr.length) {
    for (var i = result.cur + 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
      missed.push(i);
    }
  }
  return missed;
}

var a = [1, 2, 3, , 4, 5];
var missed = findMissed(a);
printRes(a, missed);

console.log(missed)

a = [1, , 3, , 5, , 7, , 9]
var missed = findMissed(a);
console.log(missed)
printRes(a, missed);

a = [1, ,,,]
var missed = findMissed(a);
console.log(missed)
printRes(a, missed);

a = [,,,]
var missed = findMissed(a);
console.log(missed)
printRes(a, missed);

a = [,,,2]
var missed = findMissed(a);
console.log(missed)
printRes(a, missed);



function printRes(src, res) {
  document.getElementById('res').innerHTML += JSON.stringify(src) + '<br/>' + JSON.stringify(res) + '<br/>';
}
```

```html
<div id="res"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are two characters that you *know* aren't in the data (such as a pound sign `#` and pipe `|`), you can use this one-liner:

```
Math.max(-1, [].concat(9, a, 9).join('#|#').split('|').indexOf('##')-1);
```

The `9`s are simply placeholders in case the missing element is at the beginning or end.  (But note that a single extra comma at the end of an array is ignored in JavaScript, so there's no way to check for that condition.)

**Snippet**

```js
console.clear();

//hole at beginning:
a= [,1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(Math.max(-1, [].concat(9, a, 9).join('#|#').split('|').indexOf('##')-1));  //0

//hole in middle:
a= [1,2,3,,4,5];
console.log(Math.max(-1, [].concat(9, a, 9).join('#|#').split('|').indexOf('##')-1));  //3

//an extra comma at the end of an array is ignored in JavaScript:
a= [1,2,3,4,5,];
console.log(Math.max(-1, [].concat(9, a, 9).join('#|#').split('|').indexOf('##')-1));  //-1  

//only the last comma is ignored:
a= [1,2,3,4,5,,];
console.log(Math.max(-1, [].concat(9, a, 9).join('#|#').split('|').indexOf('##')-1));  //5
```

Answer (score -1):

Creating an array like so `a=[1,2,3,,4,5];` will cause `a[3]` to be `undefined` and not `null`.

`a.indexOf(undefined)` or `a.indexOf('undefined')` will not work for obvious reason. Setting `a[3]` to `null` will not work either since everything that follows will be *shifted left*.

I recommend creating your own array method that will search for every `undefined` value.

```
var arr = [1,2,3,,4,5];

Array.prototype.findMissingValues = function(callback){
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
        if(typeof this[i] === 'undefined'){

            if(typeof callback != 'undefined'){
                callback.apply(this, [i, this[i]]);
            }
        }
    }
}
arr.findMissingValues(function(index, value){
    alert(value);
});
```

Comment: how it can help find index for missed element?